# Q: How can I turn this Fibonacci sequence into an array in batch programming?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, fibonacci

the script successfully calculates the fibonacci sequence but I am not sure how to turn the numbers into an array.

`Title Fibonacci array
    @echo off
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

```
:Fibonacci
setlocal
    ::C=current L=last S=Swap
    set C=1
    set L=0

    for /l %%G in (1,1,30) do (
        set S=!C!
        set /a C+=!L! & Call :Array !C!
        set L=!S!
)

:Array
    ::Here is where you create the array
    set i=-1

    for %%X in (%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9) Do (
        set /a i+=1
        set /a Fib[!i!]=%%X
)   
    set index=!i!

    for /l %%X in (0,1,!index!) do (
        echo !Fib[%%X]!

)
pause>nul
endlocal`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Title Fibonacci array
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:Fibonacci

    ::C=current L=last S=Swap
    set C=1
    set L=0

    set i=-1
    for /l %%G in (1,1,30) do (
        set S=!C!
        set /a C+=L

        rem Here is where you create the array,
        set /a i+=1
        set /a Fib[!i!]=C

        set L=!S!
    )
    set index=!i!


:ShowArray

    for /l %%X in (0,1,!index!) do (
        echo %%X- !Fib[%%X]!
    )

pause>nul
endlocal
```

**EDIT**: *Simpler method*

```
@echo off
Title Fibonacci array
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set N=30

:Fibonacci

    set /A i=0, j=1, Fib[0]=1, Fib[1]=1

    for /L %%G in (2,1,%N%) do set /A Fib[%%G]=Fib[!i!]+Fib[!j!], i=j, j+=1

:ShowArray

    for /L %%X in (1,1,%N%) do echo %%X- !Fib[%%X]!

pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Title Fibonacci array
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Fibonacci
::set counter and array index
set/a Count=30, i=0, j=1
set/a F[!i!]=1, F[!j!]=1

echo F[!i!]=1
echo F[!j!]=1
::Calculate the rest and display
for /l %%N in (2,1,%Count%) do (
    set /A F[%%N]=F[!i!]+F[!j!] 
    echo F[%%N]=!F[%%N]!
    set /A i=j, j+=1
)
```

> Ive made it more elegant by displaying it whilst calculating the remaining sequence

Answer (score 0):

**which :** keeps track of how many times we have added previous two values,for example: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 . . . . if which=4, then 0+1=1 first time 1+1=2 is second time  2+1=3 is third time and 3+2=5 is the forth time... **prev1** and **now1** are just names to keep track of which should be added to which. . . .rest logic is usual as of fibonacci

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto:main

:fibo 
    if %~1 equ !%~4! (
        goto:eof
    )
    set /a prevhere=!%~3!
    set /a %~3=!%~3!+!%~2!
    set /a %~2=!prevhere!
    set /a %~4=!%~4!+1
    call:fibo %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4
    enter code here

goto:eof

:main
setlocal
    set /a which=1
    set /a now1=1
    set /a prev1=0
    call:fibo %2 prev1 now1 which
    echo %2th fibo number = !now1!
endlocal
goto:eof
```